# C++ MFC SQLite sqlite3_exec callback

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, callback, mfc

So I'm trying to use SQLite with MFC dialogues in Visual Studio 2010. I'm unclear as how to use the callback function in order for me to save result of the query, which is trying to count the number of tables in my database, into the variable m_Results. Is there anyway to do this, or is there anyway for me to access the nTables variable?

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
    int i;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);
    data = argv[0];
    return 0;
}

BOOL CDBpracticeDlg::OnInitDialog(){
    ...

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char *sql;
    const char* data = "Callback function called";

    rc = sqlite3_open("structInfo_Test.db", &db);

    if( rc ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return(0);
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

    /* Create SQL statement */
    sql = "Select Count(*) as nTables FROM sqlite_master where type='table';";

    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, &m_Results, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        char error[200];
        strcpy(error,"SQL error: ");
        strcat(error,zErrMsg);
        m_Results = error;
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }else{
        fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
    }
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback for the [sqlite3_exec](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) API is widely underdocumented. The fact that it is purported with misleading parameter names doesn't help much, either. Providing more natural formal parameter names goes a long way:

```
static int callback(void* context,  // user-provided object (4th param to sqlite3_exec)
                    int columnCount,      // number of columns
                    char** columnValues,  // array of column values as C-style strings
                    char** columnName)    // array of column names as C-style strings
```

To update the `m_Results` object from the `callback`, you simply have to cast *context* to the correct type, and use that:

```
static int callback(void* context, int columnCount,
                    char** columnValues, char** columnNames) {
    CMyType& results = *static_cast<CMyType*>(context);
    // Use 'results' which is a reference to 'm_Results'.
    for (int index = 0; index < columnCount; ++index) {
        // Assuming CMyType has operator+=(const char*) (like a CString)
        results += columnNames[index];
        results += ": ";
        results += columnValues[index];
    }
    // Return 0 to continue invoking the callback for the remaining rows in the result
    // set. Returning non-zero will terminate the callbacks, and sqlite3_exec()
    // returns SQLITE_ABORT.
    return 0;
```

As an alternative, you can pass `this` in place of `&m_Results` to `sqlite3_exec()`, and invoke a public class member from your callback:

```
static int callback(void* context, int columnCount,
                    char** columnValues, char** columnNames) {
    CDBpracticeDlg* obj = static_cast<CDBpracticeDlg*>(context);
    // Delegate callback to class member implementation
    return obj->MyCallback(columnCount, columnValues, columnNames);
}

...

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, this, nullptr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried you solution, but I was getting errors with the
results += columnNames[index];
How do you concatenate two pointers?

Comment: @J.Ting: pass the CString to the function. Why bother with the pointers if you already have MFC

Comment: @J.Ting: Since you never told us, what type `m_Results` is, I had to assume one. This answer demonstrated, how to pass data to the callback. You'll have to work out the details on using that data yourself.